# Convert type of SQL column with an entity framework migration

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Is it possible to convert one property's type from string to binary, with a single migration, update the database and not lose data?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more column with a new type you need, than update this column by transformed data from original column, if everything is ok, drop original column and rename new.

Comment: It means I need two migrations that unfortunately is not what I want.

Comment: One migration, two table structure changes, You can do it in one transaction actually.



DO $$
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE t ADD column c2 integer;
        UPDATE t SET c2 = transaform(c1);
        ALTER TABLE t DROP column c1;
        ALTER TABLE t RENAME column c2 to c1;
END;
$$;

Comment: I think what you have written here is an SQL command, not a migration. Right?